# pip3 install failing with No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-dvxrqtnr-build/setup.py'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

trying to install python-snappy-0.5.4.tar.gz using pip3, which I had repackaged after I made changes in setup.py file which were as follows.

```
-                         libraries=['snappy'],
+                         libraries=['csnappy'],
```

failing pip

```
(venv) [root@sl2o2pocxbar301 vchauhan]# pip3 install python-snappy-0.5.4.tar.gz
Processing ./python-snappy-0.5.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-dvxrqtnr-build/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-dvxrqtnr-build/
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

as a part of debug process I extracted these files, and I am getting such messages,

```
(venv) [root@sl2o2pocxbar301 vchauhan]# tar -xvf python-snappy-0.5.4.tar.g
tar: python-snappy-0.5.4.tar.g: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
(venv) [root@sl2o2pocxbar301 vchauhan]# tar -xvf python-snappy-0.5.4.tar.gz
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.dev'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.ino'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.nlink'
./._python-snappy-0.5.4
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.creationtime'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.dev'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.ino'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.nlink'
python-snappy-0.5.4/
...................
python-snappy-0.5.4/python_snappy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
```

contents of .tar.gz files after extraction.

```
(venv) [root@sl2o2pocxbar301 vchauhan]# cd python-snappy-0.5.4/
(venv) [root@sl2o2pocxbar301 python-snappy-0.5.4]# ls
AUTHORS  LICENSE  MANIFEST.in  PKG-INFO  python_snappy.egg-info  README.rst  setup.cfg  setup.py  snappy  test_formats.py  test_hadoop_snappy.py  test_snappy_cffi.py  test_snappy.py
```

Answer (score -1):

You successfully activated your environment `venv`

I don't understand why you are using `pip3 install python-snappy-0.5.4.tar.gz`

I understand you want too install `python-snappy`

Maybe this will solve your problem: `pip install python-snappy`

The tar files generally executed as: `tar -zxvf python-snappy-0.5.4.tar.gz` and then you go to the extracted folder and execute the installation file.